# Exclude ReWriteRule for only one file while the rest redirects to php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Here is my .htaccess file and At the end you can see it redicts all html to php. But I want to exclude one file. And what If I want more than 1 file to be not redirected?

I've tried to add

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/googlede35cf4037671fba\.html$ [NC]
```

but it did not work.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule all-([0-9]+)\.html$ all.php?page=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule profile-([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$ profile.php?id=$1&user=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule upvote-([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$ upvote.php?id=$1&user=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule comments-([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$ comments.php?id=$1&user=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule post-([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$ post.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule category-([0-9]+)-(.*)-([0-9]+)\.html$ category.php?cid=$1&name=$2&page=$3 [L]
    RewriteRule userq-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ userq.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule usera-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ usera.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops. Just refreshed again and it looks like it worked. It is the correct way to exclude right? So I have more than 1 file, I can just write another ReWriteCond rule i guess?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/googlede35cf4037671fba\.html$ [NC]
```